# Data values and types

Tags: java, variables, types

Given:

```
int x = 10;
double d = -3.0;
boolean f = false;
```

**1.**

Why does the following remain a double after it is cast as an int... For the second one also, why does it output a float when defined as a long?:

```
(int) d / 2.0
(long) d * 2f
```

**2.**

Why does the first of the following print a string(?), and the latter a number?

```
"2" + x + 2
"3" + 3 * x
```

But then there is an error with the following:

```
"5" + i + 2
```

**3.**

Also, with the follwing, what is actually happening and what is the result?

```
d++ + d
```

**4.**

When Math.round is used, why does it convert the following double into a float, or are they the same thing?

```
Math.round(x / d)
```

Comment: These are lots of unrelated questions, which doesn't make it a great fit for SO...

Comment: The first and second ones are operator precedence (http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/), the third oneis missing context (what's `i`?) and the last one: just try it.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? If so, please use the appropriate tag.

Comment: @m92: But you don't have a variable called `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Why does the following remain a double after it is cast as an int... For the second one also, why does it output a float when defined as a long?:*

```
(int) d / 2.0
(long) d * 2f
```

**Because priority of cast `(int)` operator is higher that `/` and `*` operators.
You should read it like this:**

```
((int) d) / 2.0

((long) d) * 2f
```

*Why does the first of the following print a string(?), and the latter a number?*

```
"2" + x + 2
"3" + 3 * x
```

**I think it's string in both casesm you must "read" this expressions like this:**

```
("2" + x) + 2
"3" + (3 * x)
```

*But then there is an error with the following:*

```
"5" + i + 2
```

**What is the error?**

*Also, with the follwing, what is actually happening and what is the result?*

```
d++ + d
```

**This is a sequence of actions:**

1. tmp = d
2. d = d + 1
3. return tmp + d

*When Math.round is used, why does it convert the following double into a float, or are they the same thing?*

```
Math.round(x / d)
```

**It converts to `long`, because return type of `Math.round(double)` is `long`**

Answer (score 2):

**1.**

This:

```
(int) d / 2.0
```

is the same as this:

```
((int) d) / 2.0
```

Perhaps you meant this?

```
(int)(d / 2.0)
```

**2.**

They both "print" strings (assuming you're talking about using them as the argument to `System.out.println`).

These:

```
"2" + x + 2
"3" + 3 * x
```

are the same as these:

```
("2" + x) + 2
"3" + (3 * x)
```

which are the same as these (assuming `x = 10`):

```
("2" + 10) + 2
"3" + 30
```

which are the same as these:

```
"2102"
"330"
```

**3.**

I can't remember what should happen here.  But you should never need/want to write code like that, so it doesn't matter!

**4.**

The return type of `Math.round` is an integer type, not a floating-point type.

Answer (score 1):

```
(int) d / 2.0
(long) d * 2f
```

You still do floating point math, i.e. one operand is still a double/float and thus the result is a double/float.

```
"2" + x + 2
"3" + 3 * x
```

The first would just be concatenation, i.e. the type of the expression is `String` and thus all operands are converted to a string. For `x=1` you'd get `"212"`.

The second is subject to operator precendence, i.e. `*` is evaluated before `+` and thus the expression `3 * x` is an integer math operation whose result will then be converted to a string by `"3" + result`.

```
"5" + i + 2
```

The error lies in your code, post the exception. Most probably `i` is undefined.

```
d++ + d
```

Have a look at operator precedence and post increment operators. `x++` would return the value of `x` and then increment it. Then the previous value of `x` will be added to the new value. You can think of it being similar to `x + (x+1)`.

> When Math.round is used, why does it convert the following double into a float, or are they the same thing?
>   Math.round(x / d)

There's no conversion, just an overloaded method (one taking a double and one taking a float). Basically `float` has less precision than `double` but both are floating point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Too many questions in one.

- You're casting the operand, not the expression, and types will be promoted.
- What do they actually print, and how are you differentiating their types? Check out [Java operator precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).
- Because there's no `i`.
- You can print the result.

The [Conversions and Promotions JLS section](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/conversions.doc.html) may also be helpful; many of your questions are answered there.